# Facebook API: How to post to a page wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

It's the same situation as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205602/facebook-api-how-to-post-to-own-application-wall-without-login), but now I need to post a message to the wall of a Facebook **Page**.

I tried the following (the other code is the same as in the answer):

```
$facebook->api('/PAGE-ID/feed', 'post', $attachment)
```

But I get the error

> (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action`.

I think I have the wrong `access_token` for that action but where/how do I get the correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebooks documentation on obtaining access_tokens and permissions is documented on their site [Here](http://api.facebook.com).

You will need to obtain a *permanent* access_token with the permissions to post to the users status page if you want to post offline. You must have the permanent (or offline_access) token in order to do this without worrying about the token expiring.

When requesting an access_token you can add an additional permissions attribute to the GET request that is issued, in that key you specify the additional permissions you would like.

EDIT:
The process for obtaining a token with scope permission is [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/), under the section "Authorization" look at the second example. It will have a "scope" sample requesting additional permissions. The permissions used to be documented in the OAuth flow, but they seem to have moved, sorry.

Comment: I must do that automatically and without accessing manual the Facebook page, the script must get the access token automatically.

Comment: @Poru, that is not possible AFAIK. All apps must either be hosted through Canvas, or specifically launch a browser to let the user login, then provide a token back. this is all covered on the api documentation. Once the token is granted you can reuse it from another process.

Answer (score 2):

That error message sounds more like you have an access token, but the permissions are wrong. Read up on [extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

You probably need to ask for "publish_stream" when your user logs in/gives permissions on your "app".