# Post to User Wall in Facebook automatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to develop an application that automatically posts data to Facebook User's walls.

I have already contemplated the idea of having to authorize users first on facebook..

Workflow should be like:

1.- User is registered, he receives a barcode with a numeric ID.

2.- Time later the user scans barcode in embedded device, it posts the numeric ID to some php magic... and some text is published to his wall automatically, no login, no nothing, we should get the user data just based on our first registration. The (embedded device/computer/thing that reads barcodes) must be headless.

Is this even possibly with the current Facebook oAuth model??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

[Facebook API: How to post to own application wall without login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205602/facebook-api-how-to-post-to-own-application-wall-without-login)

It says 'Application Wall' in the question but the answer makes reference to the 'User Wall'.

> ...and if you want to publish to an user wall without login, you also need this user long live access token, for that you have to ask for Offline access permission.