# Automated Comment Cron Job No Longer Working: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Bad signature

Tags: php, facebook-access-token

A few months ago, I wrote a small app that would parse a string from my client's blog page and post it as a comment to their Facebook wall, which I have the credentials to manage.

The client only had to authenticate my app ONCE, and then, via the now-depricated "offline_access" permission, I could post on their behalf to their wall.

The code no longer works despite whether I use the old SDK or the latest SDK. I have attempted to migrate my code (below) to the latest version of the SDK and latest protocols for handling authentication to no avail. I have also had the client re-authenticate my app with the "manage_pages" scope (which I've had in place since day 1) with no difference.

The error I get is `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Bad signature`

I have been in circles between Facebook's documentation and the wise sage of Stack Overflow and I'm at my wit's end. I think my problem lies in not being able to generate a "long-lived" access token, but I have to be able to do this without the client having to log-in to Facebook every time (or at all, for that matter). So how do other apps like those that mirror a user's Twitter status to Facebook handle offline posting with no subsequent user login/authentication?

I noticed that my code works if I use Facebook's Graph API Explorer. But that requires me to see a dialogue and this will not work in my client's case. (Login/Re-Authentication was NEVER needed a few months ago.)

I have been pulling my hair out for the past week trying to find the answer, and I keep going in circles:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal

[Facebook API: How to post to own application wall without login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205602/facebook-api-how-to-post-to-own-application-wall-without-login)

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11839544/how-to-avoid-fatal-error-uncaught-oauthexception-when-using-cron-job

...to name a few. I feel like a spider trapped in a bathtub.

If someone could share a practical code example that suits my particular case, that would be tremendously appreciated, thanks. Here is the code that was working that I have tried to adapt to the latest Facebook PHP SDK and protocols:

```
<?php

require_once 'facebook.php';

$facebook_access_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" . FACEBOOK_APP_ID . "&client_secret=" . FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $facebook_access_token_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$facebook_access_token = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$config['appId'] = FACEBOOK_APP_ID;
$config['secret'] = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$facebook->setAccessToken($facebook_access_token);

$page_id = FACEBOOK_APP_PAGE_ID;
$facebook_access_token = "";
$result = $facebook->api('/' . FACEBOOK_ACCOUNT_ADMIN_ID . '/accounts');
foreach($result['data'] as $page){
    if($page['id'] == $page_id) {
        $facebook_access_token = $page['access_token'];
        break;
    }
}

$facebook->setAccessToken($facebook_access_token);
$attachment = array(
    'access_token' => $facebook_access_token,
    'message' => 'Test message',
    'scope' => 'manage_pages,publish_stream,publish_actions'
);

$result = $facebook->api('/' . $_GET['post_id'] . '/comments', 'post', $attachment);

?>
```

Comment: At which point in your code do you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the page access token using a **long-lived** user access token, the page token will not expire by default – so offline_access deprecation is no actual problem in such a scenario.