# Possible to post to Facebook Page wall without logging in?

Tags: php, facebook, publish

I found it quite easy to have a script to post my Twitter, but when it comes to my Facebook Page, it isn't easy.

Basically on my panel at my site I have Post to Facebook and Post to Twitter with two separate forms - the Twitter form works well, but with Facebook, I don't know how to post to the Page wall without having the need to login, as the panel will be used by other Administrators and I shouldn't need them all to login to post to the Page.

How would I go ahead by posting simply by a form without logging into the Page via PHP? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205602/facebook-api-how-to-post-to-own-application-wall-without-login

Comment: In order to create a post, there must be a user logged in, so that you can identify the source of the post.

Answer (score 1):

on your facebook page, click on Mobile, you'll see an email on which you can send your status update : xxxxxx@m.facebook.com, just add the status on the subject and/or a picture in attachment